# count unique products which have right-angled data (multi rows)

Tags: sql, google-sheets, count

Halo there,

i have spreadsheet in link below
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VpnjDJRv6zMILSqfStxjTt-I_z3Za-UUAKUbl7tkDzg/edit#gid=1264750664

i want to counts all of the product name by the list of WH_breakdown with parameters true or false. I have using countifs and it was not work because have a different size parameter (which there are many rows in WH_Breakdown (C:NX)

I want to the output maybe like these, which the total must be unique.

All helps so much appreciated.
Thank you

| WH_Code | Total Unique | True | False |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 828 | 2308 | 1821 | 487 |
| 857 | 2308 | 1821 | 488 |
| 642 | 2294 | 1806 | 488 |
| 408 | 2308 | 1821 | 487 |
| 519 | 2294 | 1807 | 487 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula I have used-

```
A2=UNIQUE(FILTER(FLATTEN(Data!C2:HD);FLATTEN(Data!C2:HD)<>""))
B2=MAP(UNIQUE(FILTER(FLATTEN(Data!C2:HD);FLATTEN(Data!C2:HD)<>""));LAMBDA(x;COUNTIFS(Data!C2:HD;x)))
C2=MAP(UNIQUE(FILTER(FLATTEN(Data!C2:HD);FLATTEN(Data!C2:HD)<>""));LAMBDA(x;COUNTIFS(FILTER(Data!C2:HD;Data!B2:B=TRUE);x)))
D2==MAP(UNIQUE(FILTER(FLATTEN(Data!C2:HD);FLATTEN(Data!C2:HD)<>""));LAMBDA(x;COUNTIFS(FILTER(Data!C2:HD;Data!B2:B=FALSE);x)))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, i have learn something from these 

Comment: If it helps then please accept the answer (tick mark it).